# How to prove that a given function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is weakly differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, weak-derivatives

For $0<r<R$, we define $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$\varphi(w):=\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1, & \lvert w\rvert \leq r \\
            \frac{log \lvert w\rvert - \log R}{\log r - \log R}, & r<\lvert w\rvert < R \\
0, & \lvert w\rvert \geq R
        \end{array}
    \right.
    $$
Then $\varphi$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\varphi$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ w\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert w\rvert = r \text{ or } \lvert w\rvert=R\}$, an obvious choice for the weak derivatives of $\varphi$ are the the classical partial derivatives $\varphi_u, \varphi_v$, which can be continued to functions on the whole real plane by
$$\varphi_u = \varphi_v = 0\text{ on }  \{ w\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert w\rvert = r \text{ or } \lvert w\rvert=R\}$$
I'm not sure if one can use the definition to prove that these functions are in fact the weak derivatives of $\varphi$, but I wasn't able to find a theorem which would guarantee the weak differentiability of $\varphi$.